# Identify table data inside table present inside a class

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <table class="s-table table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead class="p-table-head">
            <tbody class="p-table-body">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="div_2_1_2_1_2_r1" class="String CoachView CoachView_show" data-eventid="" data-viewid="Table_Column1" data-config="config_div_2_1_2_1_2_r1" data-bindingtype="String" data-binding="local.customerContacts[index].name" data-type="com.ibm.bpm.coach.Snapshot_a30ea40f_cb24_4729_a02e_25dc8e12dcab.String" data-bindingrt="local.customerContacts[0].name">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <td>
                    <td>
                    <td>
                    <td>
               </tr>
```

How to identify `td` data exist inside `div` element and click on that?

These `td` elements will generate dynamically, we need find that it consists of contact details like name & phone number..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do this. In the below example you can use ./td. This example search for a `td` which contains a value `all`. If it finds it, then click on the anchor inside the `td`.Might be useful for you.

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/thead/tr"));
        for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            WebElement webElement = iterator.next();
            List<WebElement> findElement = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("./td"));
            if( findElement.size() > 0 ){
                if( findElement.get(0).getText() != null && findElement.get(0).getText().indexOf("all") != -1 ) {
                    List<WebElement> aElement = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("./td/a"));
                    aElement.get(0).click();
                                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **id**.

```
  <td id="findme"> </td>
```

Also, it's true for any other tags. And don't forget closing opened TDs.